# Tron type game AI algorithm

Tags: algorithm, ai

Im looking for a tron AI algorithm on snap!/scratch. If not can you help me develop an AI for this game?

Comment: We can help you answer specific questions. But to allow us to do so, you could explain what you require. What is a Tron AI? And simply put: start by trying something yourself, and then tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: Please be sure to [search for existing guides and solutions](https://www.google.com/search?q=tron+ai) that you can use as starting points. Once you've made a start, we can help you solve specific problems you encounter along the way.